# Injecting UserStore and UserManager into Controller throws exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

All I wanted was to move the logic from the razor pages / model into a Controller because it ruins the organization of my project. I have a class that derives from IdentityUser.

This  means that I should replaces the usings in the razor pages with injections through the controller's constructor, for some reason it's failing and I don't know why. I tried everything I could think of - the UserStore, the UserManager always worked fine even with custom IdentityUser classes such as mine. Initially I tested with the razor pages and UserManager<ForumUser>worked, as well as the SignInManager and the UserStore<ForumUser>.

When I moved them into the controller I started getting errors of this sort

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'EweForum.Infrastructure.Data.Extensions.ForumUserStore' while attempting to activate 'EweForum.Controllers.AccountController'.

or you can replace the ForumUserStore with UserStore<ForumUser> etc. I created custom ones. Still doesn't work.

My program.cs has the AddDefaultIdentity method with the correct user - my derived one, not the IdentityUser

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EweForum.Data;
using EweForum.Infrastructure.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EweForum.Infrastructure.Data.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'EweForumContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EweForumContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ForumUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;



})
    .AddUserManager<ForumUserManager>()
    .AddUserStore<ForumUserStore>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EweForumContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.Run();
```

None of my solutions work and I don't understand what I am missing.

```
 public class ForumUser : IdentityUser


 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
     private readonly EweForumContext _context;
     private readonly SignInManager<ForumUser> _signInManager;
     private readonly ForumUserManager _userManager;
     private readonly ForumUserStore _userStore;
     private readonly Logger<RegisterModel> _logger;


     public AccountController(EweForumContext context,
                             SignInManager<ForumUser> signInManager,
                             ForumUserManager userManager,
                             ForumUserStore userStore,
                             Logger<RegisterModel>logger)
     {
         _context = context;
         _signInManager = signInManager;
         _userManager = userManager; 
         _userStore = userStore;
         _logger = logger;

     }

 public class ForumUserManager : UserManager<ForumUser>
 {

     public ForumUserManager(IUserStore<ForumUser> store,
         IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
         IPasswordHasher<ForumUser> passwordHasher,
         IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ForumUser>> userValidators,
         IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ForumUser>> passwordValidators,
         ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
         IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ForumUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
     {
     }
 }

 public class ForumUserStore : UserStore<ForumUser>
 {
     public ForumUserStore(EweForumContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
     {
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the [ASP.NET Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) container doesn't know how to resolve `ForumUserStore`. Try adding it as a service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ForumUserStore>();
```